# Black background behind panned images. Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, draggable

```
class PhotoViewController: UIViewController {

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

private var backgroundImage: UIImage

init(image: UIImage) {
    self.backgroundImage = image
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    print(image)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()






    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)
    backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage
    view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)




    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerAction(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

    let cancelButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 10.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
    cancelButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cancel"), for: UIControlState())
    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancel), for: .touchUpInside)
    let next = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (view.frame.width)-90, y: (view.frame.height)-125, width: 70, height: 70))
    next.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Next"), for: UIControlState())
    next.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancel), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(next)
    view.addSubview(cancelButton)
}




func panGestureRecognizerAction(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    view.frame.origin.y = translation.y

    if gesture.state == .ended{

        if view.frame.origin.y > 100 && view.frame.origin.y < 200{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 

                dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

            })
        } else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 

                self.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When I pan up or down and drag the image view down the background is black eventhough i specified it to be gray. How can the background be of my chosen color. If any more required info is needed to answer the question please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `panGestureRecognizerAction` is moving the *view* instead of the backgroundImageView

Comment: How can i get it to move backgroundImageView it gives me an error when i try and do that. Thanks alot for your answer anyways makes a lot of sense

Comment: There is a good tutorial here: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dragging-views-gestures-tutorial-ios10  ... Took almost no changes to match that "drag-able" UIView to a "drag-able" UIImageView.